# Sequential criterion of the limit of a function, extended to include infinity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Is the following theorem correct? It is an extended version of Theorem 4.1.1 of Strichartz's the Way of Analysis, or [this theorem from mathonline](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-sequential-criterion-for-a-limit-of-a-function). The difference is that I have tried to include the case $y= \pm \infty$, as well as the possibility that the limit itself is $\pm \infty$.

When we consider a limit point in $\bar{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \lbrace -\infty, \infty \rbrace$, we consider the topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ that makes it homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$, so that e.g. $\infty$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Theorem**

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $y \in \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ be a limit point of $D$ in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and let $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function. $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} f(x)$ exists iff for every sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \subseteq D \setminus \lbrace y \rbrace$ with $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} x_i = y$, $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}f(x_i)$ exists. If either of the statements of this equivalence holds, then the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} f(x)$ and the sequential limits $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(x_i)$ are all equal.

I have tried to prove the theorem using the substitution theorem (Theorem 4.1.4 in Mathematical Analysis by Canuto and Tabacco), properties of $f(x) = \vert \frac{1}{x} \vert$ and the original theorem that I am trying to extend. It was all a bit tedious and the proof became quite long. I could provide more details, but I hope I have shown enough effort to ask if the formulation of the theorem is correct. I want to be sure I did not make a mistake, like that the convergence of sequences is not enough and we need for example all nets have to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> we consider the topology on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ that makes it homeomorphic to $[-1,1]$

So in fact you are dealing with $[-1,1]$, thus your claim should be true. Its topological nature its simple and it should follow from the following general

**Proposition.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, the space $Y$ is Hausdorff, $D\subset X$, $y\in \overline{D}\setminus D$ and $f:D\to Y$ be a map. If there is a countable base at the point $y$ then $\lim_{x\to y} f(x)$ exists iff for every sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \subseteq D \setminus \lbrace y \rbrace$ with $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} x_i = y$, $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}f(x_i)$ exists. Moreover, if either of the statements of this equivalence holds then the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} f(x)$ and the sequential limits $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(x_i)$ are all equal.

*Proof*. Since necessity of the equivalence is evident, it remains to prove that if all sequential limits $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(x_i)$ exist then the limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} f(x)$ exists and the sequential limits $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(x_i)$ are all equal to it. Indeed, let $\{U_i\}$ be a countable base at the point $y$ such that $U_i\supset U_{i+1}$ for each $i$. For each $i$ pick a point $x_i\in U_i\cap D$. Then $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} x_i=y$, so there exists a limit $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}f(x_i)=z$. 
Let $(y_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be any sequence of points of $D$ converging to $y$. Consider a sequence $(z_i)_{i=1}^\infty=(x_1,y_1,x_2, y_2,\dots)$. There exists a limit $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}f(z_i)=z’$. Since $z’$ is also a limit of the sequence $(f(x_i))_{i=1}^\infty$, and the space $Y$ is Hausdorff, $z’=z$. Thus $z$ is also a limit of the sequence $(f(y_i))_{i=1}^\infty$. 
Now assume that $\lim_{x\to y} f(x)$ does not equal to $z$. Then there exists a neigborhood $O_z$ of the point $z$ such that for each $i$ there exists a point $y_i\in U_i\cap D$ with $f(y_i)\not\in O_z$. Then $z$ is not a limit of the sequence $(f(y_i))_{i=1}^\infty$, a contradiction. $\square$

**Update.** Countable base at a point $y$ is a countable family $(U_i)$ of its neighborhoods such that for any neighborhood $U$ of the point $y$ there exists $U_i\subset U$. The condition “there exists a (countable) sequence $(U_i)$ of open sets of $X$ so that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i=\{y\}$ corresponds to so-called countable pseudocharacter $\psi(y,X)$ of the point $y$ in the space $X$, which is weaker than the existence of a countable base at $y$ (which corresponds to countable character $\chi(y,X)$ of $y$).

In the proposition, in general, we cannot replace countability of $\chi(y)$ by countability of $\psi(y)$. Indeed, define a topology $\tau$ on the set $\Bbb R$ by putting a set $U\in\tau$ iff $U=V\setminus C$  for some set $V$ open in the standard topology of $\Bbb R$ and (at most) countable set $C$. Let $Y=\{0,1\}$ endowed with the discrete topology. For each natural $n$ put $D_n=[2^{-n},2^{-n}+2^{-n-1}]$ and $D=\bigcup D_n$. Define a function $f:D\to Y$ by putting $f|D_n=0$, if $n$ is even and $f|D_n=1$, if $n$ is odd. Then $0\in\overline{D}$, $\psi(0,X)$ is countable, and the condition “for every sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^\infty \subseteq D \setminus \lbrace y \rbrace$ with $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} x_i = y$, $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty}f(x_i)$ exists” trivially holds because no sequence of points of $D$ converge to $x$. Nevertheless, $\lim_{x\to y} f(x)$ doesn’t exist.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will need some time to think about this, which I am not sure I have right now, but I think I grasp most of it. From what I read so far I have a few questions. I could not find a definition of a countable base $(U_i)$ at a point $y$. Can this assumption be replaced by this?: Assume there exists a (countable) sequence $(U_i)$ of open sets of $X$ so that $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_i = \lbrace y \rbrace$. Furthermore in your proof you write "a countable base at the point $x$" which I think should be $y$ and I suppose "for each $n$" should be for each $i$. (...)

Comment: (...) You mix two sequences in $(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, \dots)$ which is also done in the proof of the theorem in Strichartz's book, which is interesting to me. I am curious if you studied his proof before coming up with your own, or whether this is a common technique.

Comment: @Haro I added an update concerning the countable base. Your corrections are right, thanks. I think that sequence mixing is a common technique.  I even didn't hear about Strichartz because I studied analysis and topology in Lviv (Ukraine) by local (mostly Russian) books.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I think it is helpful for me. Again, it is difficult for me to consider all the details. I will now state something that probably obvious, just to show that I thought about it and because it may be helpful to other students like myself : To see that no nontrivial sequences converge in $\tau$, note the following. If $z \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with $x_n \neq z$, then for $V = (z-1, z+1)$, we have that $U = V \setminus (x_n)$ is an open neighbourhood of $z$ in $\tau$, but clearly $x_n \notin U$. So $z$ is not the limit of $(x_n)$. (...)

Comment: (...) In particular a sequence $(x_n) \subset D\setminus \lbrace y \rbrace$ does not $y=0$.

Comment: @Haro Yes, exaclty.